# Why does malloc return a very high address not existing in /proc/pid/maps?

Tags: android, c, linux, malloc, termux

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
int main(void){
int fd,*p1,*p2;
p1=malloc(100000000);    
p2=mmap(NULL,100000000,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE,-1,0);
*p1=*p2=7;
printf("*p1=%d,*p2=%d\n",*p1,*p2);//check the 2 addresses available
fd=open("/proc/self/mem",O_RDWR);
assert(fd>=0);
pwrite(fd,"\5\0\0\0",4,(off_t)p1);
pwrite(fd,"\5\0\0\0",4,(off_t)p2);
close(fd);
printf("*p1=%d,*p2=%d\n",*p1,*p2);//check the 2 addresses available
printf("malloced at %p,mmaped at %p\n",p1,p2);
getchar();//can look /proc/pid/maps when blocking here
free(p1);
munmap(p2,100000000);
getchar();
}
```

output on Termux(arm64,Android) is

```
*p1=7,*p2=7
*p1=7,*p2=5
malloced at 0xb400007c0bf81f00,mmaped at 0x7c06021000
```

this address returned by malloc() is not in the range of /proc/pid/maps and cannot modify with /proc/pid/mem why?

when strace this,mmap(called by malloc) does not return avery high address,but malloc does and using it will not cause Segmentation fault

when free(p1) it calls munmap with a normal address which is very different with p1

this is the output of strace

```
mmap(NULL, 100012032, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7c0bf80000
mmap(0x7c0bf81000, 100003840, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7c0bf81000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7c0bf81000, 100003840, "scudo:secondary") = 0
mmap(NULL, 100000000, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7c06021000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x1), ...}) = 0
mmap(0x7d92711000, 262144, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7d92711000
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, 0x7d92711000, 262144, "scudo:primary") = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {c_iflag=ICRNL|IXON, c_oflag=NL0|CR0|TAB0|BS0|VT0|FF0|OPOST|ONLCR, c_cflag=B38400|CS8|CREAD, c_lflag=ISIG|ICANON|ECHO|ECHOE|ECHOK|IEXTEN|ECHOCTL|ECHOKE, ...}) = 0
write(1, "*p1=7,*p2=7\n", 12)           = 12
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/mem", O_RDWR) = 3
pwrite64(3, "\5\0\0\0", 4, -5476376614105768192) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
pwrite64(3, "\5\0\0\0", 4, 532676743168) = 4
close(3)                                = 0
write(1, "*p1=7,*p2=5\n", 12)           = 12
write(1, "malloced at 0xb400007c0bf81f00,m"..., 54) = 54
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x1), ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {c_iflag=ICRNL|IXON, c_oflag=NL0|CR0|TAB0|BS0|VT0|FF0|OPOST|ONLCR, c_cflag=B38400|CS8|CREAD, c_lflag=ISIG|ICANON|ECHO|ECHOE|ECHOK|IEXTEN|ECHOCTL|ECHOKE, ...}) = 0
read(0, "\n", 1024)                     = 1
munmap(0x7c0bf80000, 100012032)         = 0
munmap(0x7c06021000, 100000000)         = 0
read(0, "\n", 1024)                     = 1
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to write to `/proc/self/mem`?  Are you sure that the `open()` even succeeds?  That file is not [documented](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to be writable.

Comment: `0xb400006d712a0f00 is not in the range of /proc/pid/map` How are you checking that?

Comment: your output with the second `*p is 0` looks like it had errors (checking them out is omitted in the original). In case of successful open()/pwrite() and printing map address match at the last line, it displays something like 
`*p is 0`
 `*p is 5`
`malloced at 0x7ff0cf2a1010`
`/proc/self/maps match: 7ff0cf2a1000-7ff0d5200000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0`

Comment: after printing the address the program will be interrupted at getchar(),when you see /proc/pid/maps @KamilCuk

Comment: seeing in strace,open is successful but pwrite return EINVAL. If use mmap() to replace the malloc(),I will get a normal output like yours and the address is within /proc/pid/maps @yvs2014

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your program - after adding missing `#include <fcntl.h>` - prints for me `*p is -1094795586
*p is 5
malloced at 0x7f360efa0800`. Then I can manually check `ps x` and then `/proc/<thepid>/maps` and then the address is within range `7f360ef9f000-7f3614f00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0`. What operating system are you using? What platform are you on? What can you tell about your environment? Add error checking - is `p` null? Did `open` fail? Did `pwrite` fail?

Comment: @kawayi in the initial Q there was nothing about emulated procfs in some virtual environment, no idea

Comment: @KamilCuk I updated the detail of the question and added output of strace.Only pwrite fails, others are successful.My environment is Termux in Android 13